# Bootstrap responsive horizontal layout - determine flow?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is there a way to force the responsive design in bootstrap to break up rows in a certain way?

e.g.

I have a GUI like this:

```
[label] [input] [input] [button]
```

Currently it will break the row from the right side, first the button falls down, then the 
last input etc when the viewport shrinks.
Like this:

```
[label] [input] [input] 
[button]
```

I would like to se a break between the [label] and [input] first.
Resulting in something like this

```
[label] 
[input] [input] [button]
```

and after that the normal behaviour can kick in.

Hope this question makes any sense at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help you?

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="...">My Label</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
      <button>My Button</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesnt look right, the label is always above the rest of the controls, I only want it to wrap after the label first when wrapping is needed.